# SAMBA IP address authentication?

Tags: ip, samba, linux, network-attached-storage

I have a linux server running Samba to serve as a NAS. I would like only certain IP's to access certain files in the shares. Can this be done? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

You could edit: /etc/samba/smb.conf
and edit the Samba global variable: `hosts allow`.

Example: `hosts allow = 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.10 192.168.2.11`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [hosts allow](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#HOSTSALLOW)  directive at the share level to limit access to shares from particular hosts in your smb.conf.

```
[some share]
hosts allow = 192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.23
...
```

Note that valid user credentials are also required.